# Does $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)} {x} =0$ imply $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\} $?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I believe it does, but I can't prove it. I know that $\frac{f(x)} {x} $ is bounded, but I have no idea how to use this.
EDIT:$f$ is continuous, my bad.

Comment: $f(x) = \frac1x$ is continuous. Especially, it is continuous in any way that you care about when looking at $\lim_{x\to\infty}$.

Comment: There is actually another problem, because $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) $ does not have to exist... So the implication is unlikely to hold.

Comment: Thanks, I know that it is continuous, but I had to provide all the details of my problem.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}=0,$ but $\ln x$ is not bounded, has limit $\infty.$

Comment: Also $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\sin x$ does not exists.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.  The three simplest counterexamples I can think of are:

1) $ f(x) = 0 $.  This fails because $ \lim f(x) = 0 $.

2) $ f(x) = \sin(x) $.  This fails because $ \lim f(x) $ fails to exist.

3) $ f(x) = \ln(x) $.  This fails because $ \lim f(x) = \infty \not \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\} $.

Comment: good point in addressing all the cases with very simple examples.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What happens for $f(x) = \frac1x$, or for $f(x) = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x) = |x|^{1/2} \sin(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly makes you think so? It's not true.

As counter example, just take any (?) continuous $f\to 0$ for $x\to \infty$. If $f(x)\to 0$ then $f(x)/x \to 0$ as well. (In fact, it doesn't even have to converge to zero, it doesn't even have to be bounded it self. It's just the easiest counter example.)

Examples:

(1) $f(x) = e^{-x}$

(2) $f(x) = 0$

Here you have that
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 0 $$